# Duplicate code inside two different Interface implementations

Tags: java, duplicates, code-duplication

For every entity, I am making a controller, a service and a DAO. I have got now around 8 entities with those classes. Let's take, for example, my classes `Categorie` and `Product`.

Class `CategorieDaoImpl` implements methods from `CategorieDao`

```
@Override
public boolean insertCategorie(Categorie categorie) {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = super.getConnection();
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        session.save(categorie);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return true;
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        closeConnection(session);
    }
}
```

Class `ProductDaoImpl` implements methods from `ProductDao`

```
@Override
public boolean insertProduct(Product product) {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = super.getConnection();
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        session.save(product);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return true;
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    finally {
        closeConnection(session);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the code of the two classes is pretty similar, besides the parameters and the parameters of `save()`.

Intellij is telling me that this is duplicate code, but it isn't giving me a solution as it normally does when the duplicate code is inside a class. Any idea how I can solve this and make it better?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Most Dao classes have the same CRUS methods: get, insert, update, delete. Mostly, only the parameter is different.

Comment: There are usually two approaches: Put common code into a common base class from which your classes _extend_. Or put common code into another class and use an instance of that class in your class. Try to use the second approach (_favor composition over inheritance_). Apart from that: Too broad and/or opinion-based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One could solve the problem with an `AbstractInsertable<T>`-class that has some `public boolean insert(T t)` holding your code:

```
public abstract class AbstractInsertable<T> extends ... {
    public boolean insert(T t) {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = super.getConnection();
            session.getTransaction().begin();
            session.save(t);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            return true;
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } finally {
            closeConnection(session);
        }
    }

    [...]
}
```

The implementations could then inherit from that `AbstractInsertable<T>`, e.g. `CategorieDaoImpl extends AbstractInsertable<Category>`. This, of course, only works as long as one only inherit from one class.

The other alternative would be to work with interfaces and default implementations.

The answer ends here. The rest is my personal oppinion.

---

My personal wish would be for Java to allow multi-inheritance for those exact problems: One could define one class for each CRUD-operation and use them as mixins in the `Dao`-implementations. Default methods in interfaces are pretty close to multi-inheritance, but bear some limitations, e.g. all methods have to be `public` and no attributes can defined, which would not be present with multi-inheritance.

---

A minor remark on your code: you have a possibility for a `NullPointerException` to occur:

```
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = super.getConnection();
            [...]
        } finally {
            closeSession(session);
        }
```

Without knowing the exact implementation of `closeSession(...)`, I would not be surprise if you were not performing a nullcheck, thus a `NPE` could be thrown. If `Session` is an [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), you could use a [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). If it is not, you could use [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) to your advantage:

```
        Optional<Session> optionalSession = Optional.empty();
        try {
            optionalSession = Optional.of(super.getConnection());
            session = optionalSession.get();
            [...]
        } finally {
            optionalSession.ifPresent(this::closeSession);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm trying to implement it now and see how it works. Thanks again!

Comment: @ProxiHenn I just noticed something in your code. I updated my answer (last section). Maybe you want to take a look.

Comment: I'm doing a null check on session inside closeSession()

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be:

```
public boolean insertGeneric(Object whatever) {
    Session session = null;
    try {
        session = super.getConnection();
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        session.save(whatever);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return true;
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        closeConnection(session);
    }
}
```

Of course, the more "generic answer" could be that you use some `<T extends some BaseType>` type parameter instead of `Object`.

If there is no such base class, the next best thing would be to identify a common base interface or something that all objects you intend to save could/should/need-to implement.

In other words: your option space greatly depends on the actual signature of  `session.save()`!

Comment: @Andreas Which override? Thanks, fixed.